# Nuxt and axios: get data but does not show up in the web page

Tags: firebase, axios, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm working in my app with Nuxt, Axios and Vuetify but when I want to see the data in the browser from the get call nothing appears, only the  title. I have a info in firebase related to movie name, director and a poster of the movie but I can't see none of them.

This is my code:

```
  <template>
     <div>
        <v-app>
          <v-container>
            <h2>Películas</h2>
              <ul>
                <li v-for="peli in datosPelicula" :key="peli.id">
                     {{datosPelicula.nombre}}
                     {{datosPelicula.director}}
                     {{datosPelicula.imagen}}
               </li>
             </ul>
          </v-container>
       </v-app>
    </div>

  </template>

   <script>
     import axios from 'axios'
     export default {
      data() {
       return {
           datosPelicula: [],
      }
    },
      methods:{
       obtenerPeliculas(){
        axios.get('https://proyecto-final-cf888-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/' + 
         'peliculas.json')
        .then( (res)=>{
        let results=[];
        console.log(res);
        for (let id in res.data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(res.data[id]);
        results.push({
           id: id, 
           nombre: res.data[id].nombre,
           director: res.data[id].director,
           imagen: res.data[id].imagen,
        });
      }
      this.datosPelicula= results;
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error) 
    })       
   }
  }, 
   created(){
   this.obtenerPeliculas();
  }
 }; 
</script>

 <style scoped>
 .div{
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Small tip: You should rather use `for .. of` instead of `for .. in`

Comment: Do you get some errors in the console?

Comment: Ok, but why is that?

Comment: well, why is what?

Comment: No, no errors anywhere

Comment: could you show us how your response data looks like

Comment: Yeah, why for .. of instead of for .. in

Comment: How my response data look in the browser console?

Comment: if you do `for const peli of result.data` you can access it with `peli.nombre`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244525/discussion-between-elisaniza-and-ifaruki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling it wrong, rewrite it to:

```
            <li v-for="peli in datosPelicula" :key="peli.id">
                 {{peli.nombre}}
                 {{peli.director}}
                 {{peli.imagen}}
           </li>
```

Instead of for .. in you can use an foreach loop:

```
res.data.forEach(({ nombre, director, imagen }, id) => {
  results.push({
    id,
    nombre,
    director,
    imagen,
  });
});
```